# Traefik as Kubernetes Ingress on Azure - Assign static IP to Traefik service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, traefik

I am trying to use Traefik as a Kubernetes Ingress on Azure Kubernetes Service. While there are docs that provide information on [how to do that with Kubernetes Ingress](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip), I cannot find information about how to do that with Traefik Ingress.

Has anyone out there achieved that and can help?

PS. I am using Helm to install Traefik

Comment: tried this?
https://kumar-allamraju.medium.com/using-traefik-as-a-layer-7-ingress-controller-in-azure-kubernetes-service-2997eb29228b

Comment: already saw that article, but IP will be generated randomly as far as I can evaluate

Comment: Depends on the helm chart. My guess is the helm chart doesn't support it - technically speaking, you can roll your own helm chart to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meanwhile I found it, so I am going to answer my own question.

Like @mashov said you need

```
service:
  spec:
  loadBalancerIP: YOURIP
```

But also you need to add the following annotation

```
service:
  spec:
  annotations:
  "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group": "Resource Group that contains public IP"
```

Therefore your AKS identity needs to have the role "Network Contributor" on the resource group that holds the public IP

Comment: That annotation syntax (above) became more clear for me after seeing it used in an example on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip

Comment: This helped me: https://medium.com/geekculture/traefik-ingress-on-azure-kubernetes-service-fa498ba7e4b4

Comment: The annotations required for creating an internal load balancer (useful for private AKS) are mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb

Answer (score 2):

Before, you must create an Public IP.

And after, in values.yml file, you assign your IP:

```
service:
  spec:
    loadBalancerIP: YOURIP
```